# Image of a function that is unbounded and continuous everywhere

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f$ is not bounded above nor bounded below.
Show that if $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ then the image of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Not sure how to approach.

Comment: Hint: Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: The [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) is the way I would usually go, but we can also use the fact that the continuous image of a connected set is connected to establish that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is connected. The only connected sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are intervals. The only interval neither bounded above nor bounded below in $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $f(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(\mathbb{R})$ is an interval, that is neither bounded below nor bounded above: it must be $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: This is done with the use of IVT, which is contained in the fact that $f(\mathbb{R})$.